# class cast exception when trying to match with startwith

Tags: java

I am trying to match if a file prefix match with my object but i got a classcastexception

```
 for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            File f= files[i];
            String s=listeClients.get(i).getShortname();
            if(f.getName().startsWith(s))
            {
            System.out.println("file: " + f.getName());
            }
        }
```

I pass a string into the startwith method, so i don't understand why i got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.dev.pojo.Clients
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You shouldn't have a ; directly after the test.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. The error you posted (probably) does not occur in the code snipped you posted.

Comment: @dystroy , my bad , the ; was a typo error . There is not of course. I updated my code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is apparently that `listeClients` is *declared* as a `List<com.dev.pojo.Clients>`, but at runtime it actually *contains* a `java.lang.Boolean`. Due to the way that generics are implemented (called ["erasure"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+erasure)), the JVM can't actually detect this until it gets to

```
listeClients.get(i)
```

which it implements as

```
((com.dev.pojo.Clients)(listeClients.get(i))
```

resulting in a `ClassCastException`.

You need to find and fix the code that inserts a `java.lang.Boolean` into this list; and you probably need to pay more attention to compiler-warnings, because your compiler *probably* warned you about this possibility with a warning-message about an unchecked cast.

(In addition, as others have pointed out, you need to remove the semicolon after your `if` condition. But that's not the source of the exception you've posted about, since it takes place before that line.)

Comment: thank you for your help.  I got the problem. My clients object implements parcelable ( i am developing on android) in order to pass it through activity . My list contains 2 elements , but only the first is passed through activity. The second is transformed into boolean i don t know why